# UI/UX with two div each contain menu

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve some UI/UX like this

so there is a logo, also 2 menu, 1 for language change, 1 for change menu

[image]

my approach is two div

first div contain image and language menu ul

second div contain menu ul

but, image in first div is covered by second div

did my approach wrong?

Here is what I've done

HTML & CSS

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
}

#logo {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
}

#nav-language {
  align: right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
}

#nav-menu {
  background-color: #ccb96b;
  width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
  top: 67px;
  position: fixed;
}

#nav-menu ul {
  left: 500px;
  z-index: 5;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
}

#nav-language a {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: century gothic;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#nav-menu a {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: century gothic;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #430615;
}

#nav-menu a:hover {
  opacity: 0.36;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id='nav-language'>
    <img id="logo" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/logo.png" />
    <ul>
      <li class='navigation-Blog'><a href='#'>en</a></li>
      <li class='navigation-Crew'><a href='#'>fr</a></li>
      <li class='navigation-Promos'><a href='#'>it</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='nav-menu'>
    <ul>
      <li class='navigation-Blog'><a href='#'>home</a></li>
      <li class='navigation-Crew'><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>
      <li class='navigation-Promos'><a href='#'>contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

any help appreciated, maybe my approach could be wrong, welcome for advice

Comment: i noticed that you have `align: right;` on your `#nav-language` div, but `align` doesn't exist in css!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you're looking for by changing the `#nav-language` to `position: relative;` and changing the css on the `#logo` div's `z-index` and `top & bottom` attributes. Here's a jsfiddle

EDIT: Note that you'll have to play with the top and bottom values depending on your image size, i've used a random image as an example

EDIT2: i noticed that you have `align: right;` on your `#nav-language` div, but `align` doesn't exist in css, you'll want to set the `header` width to 100% and put `float: right;` on the language `ul`. i've updated my jsfiddle with the correct css

https://jsfiddle.net/n42dyhza/2/